# Meaning of Heap-size getting smaller over time for idle application

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I saw for a Java app that left alone idle, without user input, the heap size will go down slowly while the used-heap stays 'constant'.

I am not sure what does this means and why does it happen?

My guess is this is a JVM optimization to make the heap smaller if the app does not use it, because the heap-size will grow again when the application receives user input (used-heap goes up)

Comment: What are you using as your measure of the heap size?

Comment: I am using visualVM and watching the graph.

Answer (score 2):

The heap size will grow and shrink based on the amount of garbage produced.  It doesn't release memory back to the OS.  This is only done to improve efficiency by reducing the amount of memory accessed.